# Jquery with lightning component ($ is not defined )

Tags: lightning, html, button

I cann't use jquery selecter ( $ ) in lightning component either in controller or helper
$ is not defined error  raised

in this code , I'm trying to create html dialog with button and I want to add onclick action to that button:

```
  popupTemplate+=  '</span><br/><br/><br/><div class="commentBtn" style="color:black;font-size:12px;border:1px solid #54585a;cursor:pointer;padding:8px;" >Add Comment3</div><br/><br/>';
                     $(document).on('click', '.commentBtn', function(e){
console.log("Hello btn");
});
```

I also tried to use:

```
  popupTemplate+=  '</span><br/><br/><br/><div class="commentBtn" style="color:black;font-size:12px;border:1px solid #54585a;cursor:pointer;padding:8px;" onclick="self.openModel('+component+')">Add Comment3</div><br/><br/>';
```

so how can I $ in lightning component, please help

Answer (score 1):

This Salesforce Developers Blog [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) provides a good overview of when it is appropriate to use 3rd party libraries and when it is not.

Bottom line is that you should take on the mechanism/patterns provided in Lightning Components rather than continuing to use mechanisms/patterns from other environments. So while you could add and use jQuery, it is typically not necessary to do so. And one of the value-adds of jQuery of hiding the differences between browsers is less important given that Lightning Components require the use of modern browsers that behave more consistently: you an use the [JavaScript DOM methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp) directly.

Its well worth working through e.g. [Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) before you start working on your own components.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but what is the alternative ?
I tried document.on(...), but it said document.on is not a function

Comment: @sundus The HTML is entirely rendered by JavaScript so the normal page load lifecycle is not relevant. You should be thinking in terms of handling events in a JavaScript controller not in the page markup and making use of `aura:attibute` and `aura:if` etc. Invest the 4 Trailhead hours.

Comment: but this is html markup created at runtime ( dynamically) is is used as content of Map popup and in this popup , I want to add button with click listener

Comment: @sundus **All* HTML is dynamically created in Lightning Components. If you don't spend time learning about the Lightning Component framework you will continually run into trouble. Good luck.

Comment: I read that article and many more, I know that if I create markup in the .cmp file , I can add event by {!c. clickFunction},
but my html is created in helper file is generated at runtime

Comment: @sundus The "Lighting" way is probably to generate it in the .cmp file using `aura:if` and `aura:iterate`. That is the best place to manipulate markup.

Comment: I tried that also, but the problem is I want this markup to be displayed inside map popup (leaflet map) and not in the document, is this possible ?